# Translating matrix expression of Lagrangian into solve.qp() parameters (R)

Tags: r, optimization

I have no idea how to do this. I can set up the Lagrangian, but I don't know how to translate it into `solve.qp()` inputs.

The inputs are Dmat, dvec, amat, bvec, meq.

I don't know LaTeX so excuse my notation here. My problem is a global minimum variance portfolio optimization subject to the constraints x1+x2+x3 = 1, as well as 0 < x1 < w1, etc. Essentially, the weights must equal one, and the weights have a min/max condition.

So the matrix notation is (where Sigma is the covariance matrix of 3 assets)

```
[2*Sigma  [x1  = [0
 2*Sigma   x2  =  0
 2*Sigma   x3  =  0
 1  1  1   L1  =  1
-1  0  0   L2  =  0
 0 -1  0   L3  =  0
 0  0 -1   L4  =  0
 1  0  0   L5  =  w1
 0  1  0   L6  =  w2
 0  0  1]  L7] =  w3]
```

I know meq=1, as there is only one equality constraint. How do I translate the rest of the matrices into inputs for `solve.qp()`?

Comment: So x1,x2,x3 are the primal variables and l1,...,l7 are the dual variables and you wrote out the optimality condition in matrix form, but I think solve.qp() does not require that, it requires the statement of the minimization problem. It will compute the Lagrangian internally.

Comment: Well, I figured out that Dmat is `Sigma`, dvec is `[0,0,0]`, Amat is the constraints below Sigma, so `matrix(rbind(rep(1,NumAsset),-diag(NumAsset), diag(NumAsset)), ncol=NumAsset)`, and bvec is the vector of targets, so `[1, 0, 0, 0, w1, w2, w3]`. The problem is now I'm getting "constraints are inconsistent, no solution"

Comment: The 1st inequality constraint you have is $-x_1\ge0$ and the fourth is $x_1\ge w_1$ which indeed seem inconsistent

Comment: I guess it should be $x_1≥0$ and $-x_1≥-w_1$, so just need to change some signs.

Comment: You're right. I just had to invert my diag matrices and constraints in Amat and bvec such that the constraints were $-x_1 \geq -w_1$ rather than $x_1 \leq w_1$

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, mostly.

Dmat is your `[n x n]` covariance matrix.

dvec is your `[n]` length vector of expected returns, or if you want to find the GMV portfolio, it is a vector of 0s,.

(Can someone explain to me where this fits into the Lagrangian matrices? It doesn't matter since I only calculate the GMV portfolio subject to a target return to find an efficient frontier, then calculate the return using my solution weights, but it'd be nice to know.)

Amat is your transposed matrix of constraints `t([m x n])`, but you also have to invert the signs on your inequality constraints so that they represent `>=` constraints.

bvec is your `[m]` vector of constraints, i.e. the other side of the equation opposite the matrix of constraints.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe in the value returned to you by qp.solve() there is a vector called Lagrangian which contains the Lagrangian at the solution.